# Overriding Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer class

Tags: overrides

with this code (config.xml on my custom module):

```
<core>
<rewrite>
    <email_template>Company_Pluginname_Model_Email_Template</email_template>
    <email_template_mailer>Company_Pluginname_Model_Email_Template_Mailer</email_template_mailer>
</rewrite></core>
```

I override successfully the first model (Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template). But the second, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer not works... why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some common overwrite issues that you can look out for:

- Wrong class definition. Your class should be something like `class Company_Pluginname_Model_Email_Template_Mailer extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer`
- Wrong class file name. Your class file should be case sensitive `app/code/[community|local]/Company/Pluginname/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php`
- Cache not cleared after config.xml changes
- Module dependencies not properly configured in the module definition XML files. In your case, in `app/etc/modules/Company_Pluginname.xml` you should have a `<depends><Mage_Core /></depends>` node.
- Overwritten resource is already overwritten by another module. You could grep the PHP code for the base class name `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer`, or config.xml files for `email_template_mailer` to check if this is the case

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made everything fine, but I forgot the <depends> node on config xml.